# xpath cannot work on the Jersey REST

Tags: rest

I have a very complex XML files, when I build a java project and use xpath to parse it, it works very fine, but when I package this as a RESTFul WS, it cannot be parsed any more. Does anyone has meet this problem? I use jersey to build the REST.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document CDAdoc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(cdaDocument));

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new MetadataNamespaceContext());
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xpath.compile("/Document/Time/@value");
String creatTime =  xPathExpression.evaluate(doc);
```

In java project I can get the value of creatTime, but in REST I cannot get the value.

Many Thanks.